# Issue with jQuery and getting value from textbox

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and had the following question...

I have an input box like so: `<input class="textbox" id="query" type="text" name="querybox" />`. In jQuery i'm trying to do `$('#query').val()` and it's not able to get the value. I realized later that it's not even getting the textbox! Although I was following the docs here: 
http://api.jquery.com/?s=input

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

I have the input box in `body > wrapper(div) > content(div)`.

**EDIT**

I took away all of the irrelevant pieces to my code from this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a1 = $("#query").val();
        alert('hi');
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/static/stylesheets/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/static/stylesheets/uni_login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/static/stylesheets/navigation.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/jquery.autocomplete-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <input class="textbox" id="query" type="text" name="querybox" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I take away `var a1 = $("#query").val();`, I'm seeing the alert. Which tells me there is something wrong with the jquery i'm running...

Comment: Please provide your code. http://jsfiddle.net ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using your javascript inside document ready. You also need to load the jquery library before your own jquery scripts.

```
 $(function(){
    var a1 = $("#query").val();
    alert(a1);
 })
```

HTML

```
 <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="content">
    <input class="textbox" id="query" type="text" name="querybox" value="hello world"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

i also took the liberty to actually put something inside value attribute and display it in the alert.

[simple jquery example](http://jsfiddle.net/XXP47/)

Comment: Strange...that code is working in jsfiddle but not working locally.

Comment: I think that you should load the jquery library before your jquery scripts